# Html mobile buttons display

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on an incremental game built with HTML, CSS, and JS. I have been using buttons for the buildings and other clickable features. They look proper on a laptop or desktop, but when viewed on a tablet or phone the buttons only display one line of text.

How can I make the button display on a mobile device the same way it displays on a desktop computer?

EDIT: not 100% sure which mobile browser but my guess is chrome. (a friend tried it on his iPhone and another had the same issue on his tablet). There is not any css affecting the buttons at this time.

Here is a picture showing what I mean:

[image: incorrect and correct buttons]

This is the exact html code used:

```html
<button onclick="buyDirtHut()">
  Buy Dirt Hut<br />
  Each Dirt Hut gives you 2 population per second<br />
  Dirt Huts: <span id="dirtHuts">0</span><br />
  Dirt Hut Cost: <span id="dirtHutCost">1000</span> Gold
</button>
```

Comment: Please Post you CSS Code

Comment: He's using the default style.

Comment: which mobile browser is it?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would not use the default button tag. To make it look the same on all browsers / mobile, you can use simple styled div's. If you use the default button tag, it will show different on some (mobile) browsers. If you need any help styling your 'own custom' button. Feel free to ask.

HTML:

```
<div class="building" onclick="myfunction();">
   <!-- your content here -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.building {
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: #AFAFAF;
     color: #000000;
     width: 200px;
     height: 70px;
     float: left;
     margin: 5px;
}

.building:hover {

     background-color: #8F8F8F;
     color: #111111;

}
```

off course you have to tweak the CSS to your likings..